# Can't create EF navigation property against composite key table without both keys as columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

I don't control the schema of this existing legacy database.

One important table, let's call it `LookupTable`, is shaped like this:

```
TABLE dbo.LookupTable (

    LookupId int NOT NULL,
    LanguageId int NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (LookupId, LanguageId),

    LookupName varchar(15)
)
```

Another one, let's call it `ActualData`, has the rows of data I'm consuming:

```
TABLE dbo.ActualData(

    ActualDataId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,

    SomeDataIConsume whatever,

    ActualDataNameLookupId int
)
```

There are no foreign keys in this database, but the `ActualData.ActualDataNameLookupId` column contains `LookupTable.LookupId` values.

I want to have an `ActualData` Entity Framework POCO that has a navigation property on it that gives me the corresponding `LookupTable` Entity Framework POCO.

In reality, `LanguageId` is always `1`, and when writing SQL queries with values in that table, we always join on `AND LanguageId=1`.  So ideally, this would be a many-to-one relationship that LanguageId=1 would be part of.

If necessary, I would even accept a many-to-many relationship, having a plural `ICollection<LookupTable> ActualDataNames` property instead of a `LookupTable ActualDataName` property.  But it doesn't seem like I can even do that:

From what I can see, if you have a composite primary key on a table, and you want to get a navigation property to it, you have to ***have columns*** to map ***all*** the keys to.  I tried a few different ways to write it and would get errors like

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical.

or

> The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key
>   columns.

or

> The expression should represent a property.

My only recourse right now is to manually join them in each LINQ statement that uses them, which is undesirable.

Is there no way to have a navigation property across just ***one*** column of a composite key?

Comment: *I tried a few different ways to write it and would get errors* - examples are welcome

Comment: *I don't control the schema of this existing legacy database* - is it means that you can't change tables structure?